# Trouble with basic JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm a newbie in JavaScript programming. At our university we were just beginning to learn about JavaScript loops. So here's a code using for loop:

```
var i;
var x = new Array();
var y = new Array(1, 1, 0, 3, 5);
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    x[y[i]] = y[i];
}
```

I know that such code produces variable x to be an array with values

```
0, 1, undefined, 3, undefined, 5
```

I do not understand the logic behind it. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: What do you not understand exactly?

Comment: `i=0->x[1]=1, i=1->x[1]=1, i=2->x[0]=0, i=3->x[3]=3, i=4->x[5]=5` so x[2] and x[4] is never set

Comment: @mplungjan Waw, if the OP was having trouble deciphering the code he was looking at, this will be even more perplexing! :)

Comment: Nah. He is a university student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's loop through that one by one:

#### i=0

`x[1] = 1 //because y[0] = 1`

#### i=1

`x[1] = 1 //because y[1] = 1`

#### i=2

`x[0] = 0 //because y[2] = 0`

#### i=3

`x[3] = 3 //because y[3] = 3`

#### i = 4

`x[5] = 5 //because y[4] = 5`

So you've set values in `x` for indices 0, 1, 3 and 5, but not 2 and 4, that's why those values are `undefined`

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Let's first simplify this a bit and expand to make it more legible:

```
var x = new Array();
var y = new Array(1, 1, 0, 3, 5);
for(let i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    let key = y[i];
    x[ key ] = y[i];
}
```

On first evaluation, `i === 0`, so `key === y[0]` or `1`. Now that we have the key, we will assign the key as a value to the `x` array at the index that was the number stored in your `y` array at index `i`. So `x[y[0]] = y[0]`, therefor `x[1] === 1`.

Wrince, repeat.

Comment: Tried your code and after some mental effort I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that the positions where data is put in **Array X** are taken from **Array Y**.

As **Array Y** only have the following numbers (it means, positions): *0, 1, 3, 5*, the positions **2** and **4** will be undefined in the **Array X**

```js
var i;
var x = new Array();
var y = new Array(1, 1, 0, 3, 5);
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    console.log("Index taken from ARRAY Y where number will be put in ARRAY X: " + y[i]);
    x[y[i]] = y[i];
}
```

Comment: Informative! Took me awhile to get it, but it's crystal clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not incrementing it by the index. You are setting the index based on the value of the index of the y array.

So what you are doing in your loop is

```
x[1] = 1  // i = 0;
x[1] = 1  // i = 1;
x[0] = 0  // i = 2;
x[3] = 3  // i = 3;
x[5] = 5  // i = 4;
```

There is no value of 2 or 4, so those indexes were never defined, so it it is undefined.

What you want is

```
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    x[i] = y[i];
}
```

Comment: I read post by Thomas and then returned to yours. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write down each iteration and see how `x` changes in successive steps.

```
START           //                 []
x[y[0]] = y[0]; // x[1] = 1;       [undefined, 1]
x[y[1]] = y[1]; // x[1] = 1;       [undefined, 1]
x[y[2]] = y[2]; // x[0] = 0;       [0, 1]
x[y[3]] = y[3]; // x[3] = 3;       [0, 1, undefined, 3]
x[y[4]] = y[4]; // x[5] = 5;       [0, 1, undefined, 3, undefined, 5]
```